# Employee Time Log: Calculating time between "Clock-In" and "Clock-Out" time stamps. SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

When all Employees are selected, this query will not return calculations for every employee only most. I am trying to return results for only the times between "Clock-In" and "Clock-Out". Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.SerialNumber, it.Name AS EmployeeName, cs.Value AS 
StepValue, cs.ModifiedOnUtc AS TimeStamp, CASE WHEN cs.Value = 'Clocked-In' 
THEN NULL WHEN cs.Value <> 'Clocked-In' THEN (CASE WHEN LAG(cs.Value, 1, 0) 
OVER (ORDER BY it.Name, cs.modifiedonserverutc) 
<> 'Clocked-In' THEN NULL WHEN LAG(cs.Value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY it.name, 
cs.ModifiedOnUtc) = 'Clocked-in' THEN DATEDIFF(minute, LAG(cs.ModifiedOnUtc, 
1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY it.name, cs.ModifiedOnUtc), cs.ModifiedOnUtc) ELSE NULL 
END) END AS MinutesWorked
```